# Can I set an expired time for record with spring boot and MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I have a task to develop a simple app that handle requests (user sends requests and other accept or  reject) and I need to develop a background task that cancels all pending requests that exceed 2 minutes without receiving user accept or reject.

What is the best technique to develop this ?

I'm using Java spring boot and MySQL for the database

Comment: Did you look at https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/ ? You could schedule a task every 1 minute for example, that queries the database for pending requests that are open for 2 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

I would reccomend mysql scheduled job that works every minute and do some kind of operation like :

```
update task set status = 'reject' where taskdate < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MINUTE)
```

you can find detailed description [here](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/working-mysql-scheduled-event/)

Comment: is this way better or if the scheduled job handled by spring boot by using @Scheduled annotation for function that make the same job ?

Comment: Handling it with SpringBoot is way better.
More visibility for the backend team. You can find this thing in the code.
This DB stuff just lives in the DB and nobody knows about it.

Comment: i am database oriented. so its the best solution for me

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the Spring `@Scheduled` annotation.

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)
public void scheduleFixedDelayTask() {
    System.out.println(
      "Fixed delay task - " + System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
}
```

Here are the [details](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks) about how to setup and configure it